# ANDROID STUDIO: Gradle does not build sql database

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, gradle

I have a program where I use SQL to store the users credit. It used to work fine until one faithful day it just stopped running. Here is where the problem first occurs.

```
package com.inc.nicky.tapit;

MyDBHandler dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);

    Product product =
            dbHandler.findProduct("Coins");
    eee=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.someID);
    if (product != null) {

        eee.setText(product.getQuantity());


    } else {
    product =
            new Product("Coins", 0);

    dbHandler.addProduct(product);
    eee.setText("0");
    }
```

LogCat says that it cannot change the Text to product.getQuantity(). However if I remove this line and get to a future usage of the SQL the problem still remains; I cannot call product.getQuantity() even when I am not changing texts.

Here is more detailed report of the error:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.inc.nicky.tapit/com.inc.nicky.tapit.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2452)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1302)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1408)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4949)
        at com.inc.nicky.tapit.MainActivity.lookUpProduct(MainActivity.java:42)
        at com.inc.nicky.tapit.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:78)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
```

Here is MyDBHandler:

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "gameDB.db";
    private static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";
    public static final String COLUMN_QUANTITY = "quantity";

    public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
        TABLE_PRODUCTS + "("
        + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME
        + " TEXT," + COLUMN_QUANTITY + " INTEGER" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product.getProductName());
        values.put(COLUMN_QUANTITY, product.getQuantity());

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public Product findProduct(String productname) {
    String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " =  \"" + productname + "\"";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        Product product = new Product();

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            product.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            product.setProductName(cursor.getString(1));
            product.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
            cursor.close();
        } else {
            product = null;
        }

        db.close();
        return product;
    }

    public boolean deleteProduct(String productname) {

        boolean result = false;

        String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " =  \"" + productname + "\"";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        db.execSQL(query);
        db.close();
        return result;
    }
}
```

And the product Class:

```
public class Product {

    private int _id;
    private String _productname;
    private int _quantity;

    public Product() {}

    public Product(int id, String productname, int quantity) {
        this._id = id;
        this._productname = productname;
        this._quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Product(String productname, int quantity) {
        this._productname = productname;
        this._quantity = quantity;
    }

    public void setID(int id) {
        this._id = id;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return this._id;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productname) {
        this._productname = productname;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return this._productname;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this._quantity = quantity;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return this._quantity;
    }

}
```

What was I doing BEFORE the bug?

1. I imported the Facebook SDK and ran the application a couple of times - it was fine
2. I changed the icon of the application and debug/AndroidManifest appeared, covered in red text saying: this is not allowed here, this is not allowed there. Ever since that the SQL is not working, although it was working perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

`setText(int)` expects the `int` to be an ID of a string resource. `getQuantity()` is not returning the ID of a string resource. Hence, `setText(int)` will crash with a `ResourceNotFoundException`.

Replace:

```
eee.setText(product.getQuantity());
```

with:

```
eee.setText(Integer.toString(product.getQuantity()));
```

This will call `setText(String)` with the string representation of the `int` returned by `getQuantity()`.

Comment: Yes I did attempt that, but still no change in the result. Another issue seems to be: Unable to get provider com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider, which stops the application before the main activity

Comment: @EnderNicky: Calling `setText(String)` will not cause a `ResourceNotFoundException`. "Another issue seems to be..." -- that is a separate problem, so ask a separate Stack Overflow question for it, where you provide the separate source code and the separate stack trace for that crash.

Comment: Fixed it! Thank you so much for you invaluable help! :D You are awesome